# Removing timestamp from a column name in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
    ID  2019-01-31 00:00:00
 0  R01 1
```

How can I remove the time from the column name, so that I can slice the df by df['31/01/2019']?

Comment: is it for one column or multiple ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do something like that:

```
from datetime import datetime

df.columns = [i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') if isinstance(i, datetime) else i for i in df.columns]
```

Comment: It goes thru each column name and checks if it is of type `datetime`. If so, `strftime` simply parses it to a string according to however you want it to be formatted.